# Google Colab Library Import Problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, google-colaboratory, libraries

I tried importing Evaluation and Recommenders libraries to Google Colab. I used pip install commend the following way:

```
!pip install sklearn
!pip install scikit-learn
!pip install recommenders
!pip install evaluation
!pip install recommenders[examples]
```

And then I ran the following command and it was not able to find the modules Evaluation and Recommenders

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import time
import joblib

import Recommenders as Recommenders
import Evaluation as Evaluation
```

I searched online and saw one comment saying that tensorflow version needs to be changed. But Google colab does not support that version.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
```

Not sure what to do

Comment: what exactly are these recommenders and evaluation libraries? provide links.

Comment: I am using this github for a reference and am trying to recreate the code with my own dataset: https://github.com/dvysardana/RecommenderSystems_PyData_2016/blob/master/Song%20Recommender_Python.ipynb

Comment: Those are .py files in that repo, you cannot install them with pip. So your whole methodology is not correct.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was a library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a library but rather a code that was included in a github

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).